# TTWebController/TTNavigator invocation, not animating + dismissal problem

Tags: iphone, three20

I'm having a problem implementing the TTNavigator + TTWebController to capture links in styled labels and open them in the TTWebController.
In my current UIViewController (not a navigation controller), in the viewDidLoad i added (according to TTCatalog sample):

```
TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
navigator.supportsShakeToReload = YES;
navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeAll;

TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
```

and i've also added in the same UIViewController .m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)URL {
     [[TTNavigator navigator] openURL: URL.absoluteString animated: YES];
     return YES;
}
```

Now, if i tap on links in the styled labels, they actually open perfectly in the Three20 WebController.
I've also customised aspect, colors, title and buttons.
The problem is that the transition between my current UIViewController and the web page is without animation. I'd really need it to slide from bottom to top (as it's the default animation of the whole application).
I've played with the various settings in the TTNavigator.m, tried lots of things but still can't figure out how to perform the animation.
I'm also having problems dismissing the browser view. I've added a "cancel/done" button, but dismissal doesn't work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks in advance,
   Luca

Comment: It seems my problem is that the Three20 engine doesn't find a NavigationController on the underlying interface and so it cannot push/pop properly.
I've set up a new project with Three20 and it seems to work smoothly. Unluckly i need to *migrate* the actual code to the new working project to make it Three20 compliant.

Answer (score 0):

"It seems my problem is that the Three20 engine doesn't find a NavigationController on the underlying interface and so it cannot push/pop properly"

this is a problem for me actually, though its to do with using the Three20 Navigator with a UITabBar...

if you have any information on how you got your project working, let me know.

Comment: I recreated the project from scratch, using this template:
http://github.com/jdg/Project-Templates/tree/master
It's fully working now and i could re-use all my code (my previous project was 98% complete).
Let me know if i can help any further.
Luca